# Messenger bot call button error

Tags: bots, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I created a bot & it's working absolutely fine. But when it comes to call button template, it gives wrong number in the phone. Code is:

```
{
 "facebook":{
  "attachment":{
     "type":"template",
     "payload":{
        "template_type":"button",
        "text":"Need further assistance? Talk to a representative",
        "buttons":[
           {
              "type":"phone_number",
              "title":"Call Representative",
              "payload":"+919999999999"
           }
        ]
     }
  }
 }
}
```

And the Output in the dialer is:

```
14532944069596463097807
```

Comment: It's working inside the browser but not in messenger app.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/145540969486699/

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. The button works perfectly of ios. Any solutions to this?